# Jenkins: Start and Stop an defined Azure VM as Build Agent

Tags: azure, jenkins, pipeline

is there a way to start an Azure VM that already has all the dependencies installed that I need for my project and has also registered the Jenkins agent when the build pipeline is triggered?

Background:
I have a Jenkins job that runs on a Git push. Since the agent machine is relatively expensive, it should only be started when needed and then shut down again afterwards.

I have already tried using the Azure VM Agents Plugin, but it seems I have to work with images that create a new VM each time, which I don't quite understand.
I also tried using the AZ-Shell to start and stop the server, which works, but since the agent is stopped, Jenkins doesn't recognize the agent at runtime of the pipeline and aborts the build job.

Is there a better way to implement this in general? Am I missing something?

I would be very grateful for any help.

I have already tried using the Azure VM Agents Plugin, but it seems I have to work with images that create a new VM each time, which I don't quite understand.
I also tried using the AZ-Shell to start and stop the server, which works, but since the agent is stopped, Jenkins doesn't recognize the agent at runtime of the pipeline and aborts the build job.

I used the command
"az vm start --name {{VM-Name}} --resource-group {{group}}"
and
"az vm deallocate --name {{VM-Name}} --resource-group {{group}}"